# tkinter движение объекта за мышкой

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь сделать чтобы объект двигался в сторону мышки, но не выходил за границы, но что-то явно я не то написал.

```
from tkinter import *

def MouseMove(event):
    side = canvas.bbox(square)
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = side
    pos_x = x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2 + event.x
    pos_y = y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2 + event.y
    if 0 <= pos_x <= 50 and 0 <= pos_y <= 50:
        canvas.move(square,event.x,event.y)
    window.after(10,MouseMove)

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')

canvas = Canvas(window, width=50, height=50)
square = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,20,20, fill="red")
canvas.place(x=200, y=50)

window.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)

window.mainloop()
```

мне нужно чтобы объект двигался (стремился в сторону курсора) в пределах canvas, но отслеживалось все за пределами canvas

Answer (score 1):

У вас возникает ошибка, т.к. в строке `window.after(10,MouseMove)` вы не передаете обязательный аргумент `event` для функции `MouseMove`. Чтобы исправить это, добавьте аргумент: `window.after(10, MouseMove, event)`.

Но вам тут в принципе не нужен `after`. Он нужен был бы, если бы движение вашей фигуры не зависело бы от движения мыши (если была бы просто анимация). В вашем случае из строки `window.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)` следует, что при движении курсора функция `MouseMove` и так будет вызываться.

Чтобы фигура не выходила за пределы канваса, вы можете двигать её только при движении курсора внутри канваса, а не внутри всего окна `window`. Для этого привязывайте функцию к канвасу, а не к окну: `canvas.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)`

`move` перемещает элемент на канвасе не к определенной координате, а на передаваемое расстояние `x, y`. Поэтому логику функции`MouseMove` вам надо переписать.

Вот так может выглядеть ваш код:

```
from tkinter import *


def MouseMove(event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(square)
    canvas.move(square, event.x - x2, event.y - y2)


window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')

canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, bg='white')
square = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="red")
canvas.place(x=200, y=50)
canvas.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: расписали по делу, только вот мне нужно чтобы объект двигался (стремился в сторону курсора) в пределах canvas, но отслеживалось все за пределами canvas